# Push Notification Service

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have read the article about Push Notification Service, but I am still confused.  I’m a new for MS window phone application developing. My application needs to get the data in the whole class from web service that is for the specific organization.   Hope someone can answer my question as below.

1. In my application, the phone rings and the user answer the phone during sending the request to the web request to get the data.  What will happen if the web service sending back the respond?
2. In the above situation, do I need the Application Push Notification service?
3. I retrieve the data by using DataContractSerializer. If I need the Push Notification Service, is it meaning that I need to modify the webservice for returning the xml instead of the whole class?

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)? This helped me understand it!

Comment: Could you specify the title like *Windows Phone 7 Push Notification Service* or *Windows Phone 7 Understanding Push Notification Service"? Reason: There are way too many *push services* around these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ongoing call will not disrupt the web request-response flow hence you need not be troubled about it